# Mapping the extra mouse buttons to page up and page down

Tags: mouse, button, remapping

I am trying to map the extra mouse buttons to <kbd>PgUp</kbd> <kbd>PgDn</kbd> using xbindkeys. I found their button # using xev

> ButtonRelease event, serial 25, synthetic NO, window 0x4000001,
>       root 0x191, subw 0x0, time 597428, (80,39), root:(163,159),
>       state 0x100, button 8, same_screen YES
>
> ButtonRelease event, serial 25, synthetic NO, window 0x4000001,
>       root 0x191, subw 0x0, time 597428, (80,39), root:(163,159),
>       state 0x100, button 9, same_screen YES

Then I created the .xbindkeysrc and added the following lines:

```
"xte 'key PgUp'"
b:8

"xte 'key PgDn'"
b:9
```

and complied using `xbindkeys -p`.

But both the mouse buttons are acting as <kbd>PgDn</kbd>. What could be wrong here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct key names are "Page_Up" and "Page_Down". You can find a list of other available named keys by running `xte -h`.