# launch a command when joystick button is pressed

Tags: keyboard, emulation

I am looking for a way for make ubuntu able to map one certain key on my arcade stick as "esc" key on keyboard.

I am building a ubuntu based bartop and everything works fine except some emulators that, for exit force me to use the keyboard esc key and there is no way to map other keys.

is there a way to do it ? Is since one week i am looking around for some working solution but without success

I am running Ubuntu 18.0.4

Thanx in advance for any help

Comment: Unless there is a Ubuntu driver for the joystick I very much doubt you can do that.

Comment: but the joystick ( dragonrise ) is correctly recognized and usable , also if I runn jtest all the buttons are correctly recognized

Comment: Where in the question have you given that info? You get help based on what you say in the question. So 2 things. 1. Edit the question and add that detail. 2. What else have you failed to include?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, it is basically the same question of 'binding key on mouse button' [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1160364/mapping-the-extra-mouse-buttons-to-page-up-and-page-down)

Answer (score 0):

Open Terminal and run `xev` to check the code of the button you want.

When you press the button to asign `ESC` you read

```
ButtonPress event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0x6400001,  
root 0x1db, subw 0x0, time 152278931, (159,99), root:(1901,151),  
state 0x0, button 3, same_screen YES
```

Something like this, important point is `button 3` that is the number you need to know.

Then edit `$HOME/.xbindkeysrc`
Add

```
"xte 'key Escape'"  
b:3+release
```

Reload the `.xbindkeysrc` by `killall -HUP xbindkeys`

*Note: the number of your mousebutton probably is not 3.*